# C one dimensional array - invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript

Tags: c, arrays

I'm supposed to write a function that takes two arguments: number *n* and an array of *n* elements. The function then gives value 0 to every argument in the array. However I keep getting this error: *invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript*. No idea what am I doing wrong. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a;
int zeros(int n, int arr);

int main () {

    printf("Input array size:\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    int array[a];

    zeros(a, array[a]);

    return 0;
}

int zeros(int n, int arr) {

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<=n; i++) {
        arr[i]=0;
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: How come the arguments for `zeros` look both the same when one is suooposed to be a number, the other an array? (Also: `array[a]` is one beyond the valid range of the array.)

Comment: `int zeros(int n, int arr)` should be `int zeros(int n, int *arr)` or `int zeros(int n, int arr[])` (which is the same).

Comment: Seriously, look twice on your code before posting it here. Since when is `int arr` an array?

Answer (score 3):

You define `zeroes` to receive an `int arr` as parameter and then you handle it as an array. That won't work. Use:

```
int zeros(int n, int *arr) {

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        arr[i]=0;
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Note also the `i<n` and not `i<=n` as the array elemens are 0...n-1.

In `main` you must now call it as:

```
   zeros(a, array);
```

Comment: and `zeros(a, array[a]);` is fine?

Comment: @SouravGhosh, no, is not fine, `zeros` wants a pointer to `int` (not an `int`). You know that ;) why do you ask this?

Comment: Better yet, use an array instead of a pointer: `int zeroes (int n, int arr[n])`.

Comment: @AlterMann emm..that was a rhetorical question, posted before the edit... :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh, Ok, I get it ;)

Comment: @SouravGhosh thanks for pointing out the calling error

Comment: @Lundin, there is no need to use VLA's in this case, do you mean `int arr[]` instead of `int arr[n]`?

Comment: @AlterMann No, I mean't exactly what I wrote. The VLA will decay into a pointer to the first element, a `int*`. So functionally it is the very same thing. The advantage of the array style is greatly increased type safety when using good compilers or static analysis tools.

Comment: @Lundin, maybe I'm wrong, but there is a trend ... don't use VLA's in new projects: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5129238

Comment: @Lundin, isn't `int zeroes (int n, int arr[n])` the `n` in `int arr[n]` compile time? Then that won't work as `n` is not known at compile time.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, this is how VLA's operates, they are normally placed on the stack but unknown at compile time.

Comment: @AlterMann Nah, just because they are no longer mandatory in C11, which was probably just to sate low-end embedded systems, some people got paranoid and thought you should stop using them entirely. The same kind of low-end systems don't have to implement stdio.h or stdlib.h etc either. There is no reason why you would use a compiler that doesn't support VLAs, just as there is no reason why you would use one that doesn't support stdlib.h. And of course various old farts who have not evem learnt C99 yet took that as an excuse to not update their knowledge to the current millennium...

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Yeah it will only increase type safety if `n` can be calculated at compile-time. But it still increases safety somewhat, as you can rule out array-out-of-bounds bugs from inside the function. And it is a form of self-documenting code.

Comment: @Lundin, it  makes sense

Comment: @Lundin, if `n` is used in run-time for type-safety,would that mean the compiler must add bound checks code to check the bounds in run-time, (which is against my/the C principle that the programmer will know the assembler the compiler will generate, which excludes unexpected, slowing, code such as this), or would that mean the compiler will follow all control paths in the function to ensure no out of bounds condition _can_ occurr?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I very much doubt any compiler will do that. But I suppose it might help run-time code coverage tools to do a better job. You'd have to ask some tool expert.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: As a function parameter declaration, `int arr[n]` is treated exactly the same as `int *arr`; it's still declared as a pointer, not an array.  The array style declaration could help static analysis tools, but offers no runtime protection against array bounds errors (C does no bounds checking on array accesses, regardless of how the array is declared/allocated).

Comment: @John-Bode, so may I conclude that a function parameter declaration `int arr[n]`, meaning exactly the same as `int *arr` has __no__ added value for the language. Why did anybody put it in?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: Can't speak for either Ritchie or WG14, but I'll speculate that it's a combination of historical reasons and to more clearly document the intent of the parameter.  In B (one of the languages from which C was derived), pointers were declared using an empty `[]` instead of the unary `*`, such as `auto ptr[];`.  And declaring a parameter as `int arr[N]` makes it clear that the parameter is intended to be used as an array, rather than just as a pointer to a single item, regardless of its actual type.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your comments, I'm a beginner and I get confused a lot. However, after editing the code like @PaulOgilvie said, I now get this error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int' [-fpermissive] . Here's a pastebin with the edited code in case I misunderstood and edited something wrong: http://pastebin.com/15n2U0JV

Comment: Dear chili, you must of course also adapt the prototype to `int zeros(int n, int *arr);`. I thought we could leave this safely to you, but maybe you should read a bit more about C...

Answer (score 0):

When defining an array, an integer constant should be provided. Using a variable is illegal. Also, when passing an array to a function don't provide an index. The starting address of an array(unindexed array name) is like a pointer.